# How to troubleshoot the ".Net Runtime Error" for COR_PROFILER

Tags: event-viewer, .net-runtime

> .NET Runtime version 4.0.30319.0 - Loading profiler failed.
> COR_ENABLE_PROFILING was set properly, but COR_PROFILER was not.
> COR_PROFILER must be set to the CLSID of the profiler to load. Process
> ID (decimal): 2968. Message ID: [0x2500].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.